# Countdown timer that redirects upon completion

Tags: javascript, redirect, countdown

I have been trying to find a script (preferably JavaScript) for a countdown timer for a specific time and date (i.e. `9am GMT June 17th 2013`).  When the countdown completes (i.e it is after `9am GMT on June 17th`), I want the site to start redirecting automatically to another page.

Comment: What have you tried? There are many solutions on the web for this simple task.

Answer (score 0):

I actually wrote a simple countdown script for when we were having LAN parties with coworkers :-)

I didn't take the time to make it a jQuery plugin and it has a weird structure, but it works and you can modify it to your needs.

http://jsfiddle.net/Y6n9W/

```
(function($, undefined) {
    countdown = function(settings) {
        var _this = this,
            defaults = {
                end: '30.09.2012 09:00'
            }, rDate = /(\d+).(\d+).(\d+) (\d+):(\d+)/;

        _this.settings = $.extend(defaults, settings);

        var matches = _this.settings.end.match(rDate);

        _this.endDate = new Date(matches[3], matches[2] - 1, matches[1], matches[4], matches[5], 0, 0);

        _this.nDays = $('<span />').addClass('countdown days').html('0');
        _this.nHours = $('<span />').addClass('countdown hours').html('0');
        _this.nMinutes = $('<span />').addClass('countdown minutes').html('0');
        _this.nSeconds = $('<span />').addClass('countdown seconds').html('0');

        _this.settings.element.append(
            $('<span />').append(
                _this.nDays,
                ' Days'
            ),
            $('<span />').append(
                _this.nHours,
                ' Hours'
            ),
            $('<span />').append(
                _this.nMinutes,
                ' Minutes'
            ),
            $('<span />').append(
                _this.nSeconds,
                ' Seconds'
            )
        );

        countdownMethods.start.call(_this);

        return _this;
    };

    var countdownMethods = {
        start: function() {
            var _this = this,
                interval = 0;

            var updateTime = function() {
                var now = new Date(),
                    diff = Math.round((_this.endDate - now) / 1000);

                if(diff < 0) {
                    diff = 0;
                    clearInterval(interval);
                    window.location.href = 'newurl..';
                }

                var days = Math.floor(diff/86400);

                diff -= days * 86400;

                var hours = Math.floor(diff/3600);
                diff -= hours * 3600;

                var minutes = Math.floor(diff/60);
                diff -= minutes * 60;

                _this.nDays.html(days);
                _this.nHours.html(hours);
                _this.nMinutes.html(minutes);
                _this.nSeconds.html(diff);
            };

            updateTime();

            interval = setInterval(function() {
                updateTime();
            }, 1000);
        }
    };
})(jQuery);
```

And you use it like this:

```
$(function() {
    var counter = countdown({
        end: '08.05.2013 15:15',
        element: $('div')
    });
});
```

Comment: Fantastic! Thank you SO much! But one question (sorry Im a newbie), where do I edit to enter the page address that I want it to redirect to when the countdown end? Also is this countdown set to a specific time zone?

Comment: My original countdown didn't have the redirect feature. But if you take a look inside the `updateTime` function I added a text `newurl..` which is where the url goes, you can also make it a parameter. This countdown function just uses the timezone of the user entering the page. So if you need to account for that, you need to have your server write the current date and time, and have the script account for that.

Comment: Perfect, thank you so so much thebreiflabb. I really appreciate your help